# 'Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll" '

Tags: java, eclipse, dll, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I have looked for a solution, but all the ones I found didn't work.

- I have triple checked that I have both 64 bit JRE/JDK and Eclipse
- I have added the '-vm' argument to the eclipse.ini file.

Here's the file content:

```
 -startup plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
 --launcher.library plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130807-1835
 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
 --launcher.defaultAction openFile
 --launcher.XXMaxPermSize 256M
 -showsplash org.eclipse.platform
 --launcher.XXMaxPermSize 256m
 --launcher.defaultAction openFile
 --launcher.appendVmargs
 -vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\javaw.exe
 -vmargs
 -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
 -Xms40m
 -Xmx512m
```

EDIT: It works now, the vm argument was pointed to the wrong file!

Comment: What is your `JAVA_HOME` set to? Try `set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45"`.

Comment: The parameter to `-vm` (and the other -xxx options) should be on a separate line following the parameter, not on the same line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have updated your jdk to 7 you are most likely to face this problem.

This happens mainly due to

1. Incompatible sdk and jdk versions
2. Using a 32 bit java version for your 64 bit eclipse JVM
   (programfilex86-java)

WHAT YOU HAVE TO DO :

Firstly check the "eclipse.ini" file to see if you have a path that is pointing to your JDK

It should look something like this

```
-vm    
C:\Program Files\Java\blah\blah\blah\javaw.exe
```

if not then locate the jdk 7 javaw.exe file
sample : `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin\javaw.exe`

Paste `-vm` and the path below it into your eclipse.ini file

```
-vm    
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin\javaw.exe
```

Make sure that you type the above just before the `-vmarg`s and after the `OpenFile`.

Comment: I made update on environment variable path as i had two jdk(11 and 1.8) after which this error was showing and Worked for me too..

Comment: the 'just before ...' is important. thanks

Answer (score 0):

just check for all classpaths, etc. Have only one isntance of your JAVA_HOME and set the path to %JAVA_HOME%/bin and remove any occurances of 'jre' from 'classpaths', etc. It should start working !!

Answer (score 0):

-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin\javaw.exe

Work for me